# Restrict access to non-api view in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm building a website with a REST API backend using [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and token based authentication from [djoser](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser).

The site has user pages that are editable through an admin page (e.g. `<page-url>/admin`)
and they should not be accessible unless you are the owner. What is the best way to restric acces to non-api views when `request.user` is not available?

Comment: Are you using flatpages or something else for user pages?

Comment: Data for the pages is stored in database and rendered from JSON on the front end. The pages that should be restricted point to static html with included javascript etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple ways to restrict access for annonymous users:

1. Just add a rule for non request.user access for a view:

   ```
   def admin_view(token):
       if not Token.objects.get(token=token):
           return redirect('%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL))
   ```
2. Add a decorator for your admin views:

   ```
   from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

   @login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
   def admin_view(view):
       ...
   ```

   In this case, you have to update the login_required mixin in the base class or edit the default auth/permissions middleware, but it depends of the behaviour of your actual auth system.

Answer (score 0):

I am using decorators to restrict access for anonymous users.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = patterns(
url(r'^page_url/$', login_required(MyView.as_view())),
)
```

Also for translation I modified the TemplateView. You can create a TemplateView class to restrict access for static pages.

```
class TemplateView(TemplateResponseMixin, ContextMixin, View):

    """
    A view that renders a template.  This view will also pass into the context
    any keyword arguments passed by the url conf.
    """
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            current_user = request.user
            if current_user.is_authenticated() and (bool(request.path_info == '/') or bool(request.path_info == '/login/')):
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard')
            current_language = current_user.language_code
            translation.activate(current_language)
            context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
            return self.render_to_response(context)
        except:
            context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
            return self.render_to_response(context)
```